# How can I apply an attribute that is already a global filter to a method without it running twice?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, handleerror

I have extended `HandleErrorAttribute` in MVC by creating my own attribute that handles exceptions raised during Ajax requests. That attribute is here:

```
public class AjaxAwareHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public string PartialViewName { get; set; }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        ExceptionHelper.HandleException(filterContext.Exception, false); // custom static class and method
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        // Use partial view in case of AJAX request
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var result = new PartialViewResult {ViewName = PartialViewName ?? "~/Views/Errors/DefaultAjaxError.cshtml"};
            filterContext.Result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is default behavior in the case when `PartialViewName` is null. This is because I have it registered as a global filter in my Global.asax file:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AjaxAwareHandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

So the way this is set up, I have default behavior when an exception is raised during an Ajax call, namely that DefaultAjaxError.cshtml will be returned. In cases where I want a custom message, I create a view and pass it as `PartialViewName` to an attribute directly on the action, like this:

```
[AjaxAwareHandleError(PartialViewName = "~/Views/Errors/CustomAjaxError.cshtml")]
public ActionResult SomeAjaxControllerAction()
```

The problem in cases where I have a controller decorated with the controller action is that the code in the `AjaxAwareHandleErrorAttribute` class is running twice, presumably because it's registered globally and because it's on the method as well. Is there a way I can prevent it from running twice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `filterContext.ExceptionHandled` property to true.

Then, at the top of your override, check whether that property is true and return immediately.

Comment: Perfect, worked for me. However, for my general knowledge, I'm still curious if there is a way to prevent an attribute from running twice that doesn't necessarily deal with Exceptions.

Comment: @MattPowell: You could store a flag in `HttpContext.Items`.